# D'où vient le féminin d'aigu, exigu, ambigu… ?

Tags: genre, diacritiques

De nombreux mots en *-gu* prennent leur féminin en *-uë*. Quelle en est l'origine, et pourquoi cela se prononce-t-il *u* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le [tréma](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tr%C3%A9ma) sur le *E* assure que le groupe *UE* n’est pas un digramme, c’est-à-dire que les deux voyelles sont à considérer comme deux entités non-liées. On doit donc prononcer le *U*, qui est suivi d’un *E* ici muet, qu’on ne prononce donc pas.

En l’absence du tréma, les trois dernières lettres *(GUE)* formeraient le son /ɡə/, le U n’étant ajouté avant le E que pour durcir le G (qui autrement se prononcerait /ʒ/).

Traditionnellement, la seconde voyelle reçoit le tréma, mais les rectifications orthographiques de 1990, approuvées par l’Académie française sans toutefois leur donner un statut impératif, indiquent que :

> le tréma est placé sur les voyelles qui ont besoin d’être prononcées, et uniquement celles-ci. On écrira ainsi : gageüre, argüer, ambigüe.

Il y a donc eu introduction du tréma dans les deux premiers exemples, ce qui aura comme avantage de ne pas provoquer les prononciations erronées, mais communes :

> - /ɡaʒœʁ/ plutôt que /ɡaʒyʁ/
> - /aʁɡe/ plutôt que /aʁɡɥe/

Et déplacement du tréma vers la gauche pour les adjectifs en *-gu* :

> - aigu → aigüe
> - ambigu → ambigüe
> - exigu → exigüe

Comme les anciennes graphies demeurent jusqu’à nouvel ordre valides, *gageure*, *arguer*, *aiguë, ambiguë* et *exiguë* sont encore acceptées.

Comment: Tu m'apprends que *arguer* se prononce *ar-gu-er*. Idem pour *gageure*.

Comment: Les avantages de l'alphabétisation sont immensément nombreux, mais elle a eu de menus inconvénients, dont ces quelques mots que nos ancêtres connaissaient et prononçaient correctement, et dont nous changeâmes la prononciation à la lumière de leur orthographe. :-)